# Preserve `&nbsp;` in NSString?

Tags: iphone, html, nsstring

I want to preserve the entry of `&nbsp;` in an iPhone application text field.  However, logging and subsequent viewing of the UItextField suggest this string is getting turned into a plain old space...

When I add `&nbsp` to the text field, it goes as single characters until the final semicolon, at which point it disappears from the log message and is seen as simply a single space, thus...

MyApp[17425:20b] Log the string  &nbsp1234

//I add the semicolon here...

MyApp[17425:20b] Log the string   1234

What I want to do is prevent `&nbsp` from being converted automatically - so that it can later be sent to a website and seen as HTML.  Can I even do that with NSString or will it require something else?

Edit: I should have also said that I'd prefer for the UITextField to also display this after I save the data to an array and re-populate the UITextField from the array...  I guess it all boils down to whether NSString is really converting this or if it just hides it...  Guess I'm not clear on what goes on to auto-magically turn `&nbsp` into a space (at least for display) with NSString...

Edit 2: 8/10/09  Apologies if this is incorrect usage, I couldn't get the interface to allow me to post an "answer" nor could I add a comment...

In answer to Matt's question I will post some code, inside another edit...  Also of interest is the logging of the "count" of the string between when the string contained &nbsp and when it contained `&nbsp;`...  What I found interesting is that it seems the count decreases when I "complete" `&nbsp;` by entering the semicolon...  Originally this resulted in the following error because (I think) the count of the string and the count of the range differed as soon as `&nbsp;` is completed (I'll post code in a bit)...  -[NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'

I fixed the crash error by using the string count in the code instead of the range count, but it's still interesting and the "literal" `&nbsp;` is no longer displayed in the text field...

2009-08-08 14:58:26.319 [17897:20b] this is str::-->  `<p class="blankline">` &nbsp

2009-08-08 14:58:26.320 [17897:20b] this is str's count 27

//at this point I enter the semicolon and the string count drops back...

2009-08-08 14:58:28.095 [17897:20b] this is str::-->  `<p class="blankline">`

2009-08-08 14:58:28.096 [17897:20b] this is str's count 23

2009-08-08 14:58:31.223 [17897:20b] this is str::-->  `<p class="blankline">`  a

2009-08-08 14:58:31.223 [17897:20b] this is str's count 24

2009-08-08 14:58:31.319 [17897:20b] this is str::-->  `<p class="blankline">`  as

2009-08-08 14:58:31.320 [17897:20b] this is str's count 25

2009-08-08 14:58:31.423 [17897:20b] this is str::-->  `<p class="blankline">`  asd

2009-08-08 14:58:31.423 [17897:20b] this is str's count 26

2009-08-08 14:58:31.527 [17897:20b] this is str::-->  `<p class="blankline">`  asdf

2009-08-08 14:58:31.527 [17897:20b] this is str's count 27

Edit 4 8/10/09 : posted above code because it wouldn't show up otherwise...

Thanks Matt, interesting indeed... as I was posting my comments it occurred to me that it might be an issue with TextView -- I tried changing a couple of settings in IB, but nothing changed in terms of the "disappearing" `&nbsp;`  My thanks for your time!

Edit 3: 8/10/09

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)aTextView {
    [self updateTextViewPlacehoderFieldStatus];

    if (dismiss == YES) {
        dismiss = NO;
        return;
    }

    NSRange range = [aTextView selectedRange];
    NSArray *stringArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http:", @"ftp:", @"https:", @"www.", nil];

    NSString *str = [aTextView text];
    NSLog(@"this is str::-->  %@", str);
    NSLog(@"this is str's count %d", str.length);
//as soon as I enter the semicolon, the printout of this log message displays a single space and the count decreases...
    int i, j, count = [stringArray count];
    BOOL searchRes = NO;

    for (j = 4; j <= 6; j++) {
        if (range.location < j)
            return;

        NSRange subStrRange;
       // subStrRange.location = range.location - j;
        //I took this out because adding &nbsp; to the post caused a mismatch between the length of the string from the text field and range.location
        //both should be equal, but my best guess is that the OS/Cocoa interprets &nbsp; as ONE space.
        //This caused NSString *subStr = [str substringWithRange:subStrRange]; to fail if the user entered &nbsp; in the text field
        subStrRange.location = str.length -j;
        subStrRange.length = j;
        [self setSelectedLinkRange:subStrRange];

       NSString *subStr = [str substringWithRange:subStrRange];
//Code crashed here with error -[NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'
//I fixed this by using str.length instead of range.location

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            NSString *searchString = [stringArray objectAtIndex:i];

            if (searchRes = [subStr isEqualToString:[searchString capitalizedString]])
                break;else if (searchRes = [subStr isEqualToString:[searchString lowercaseString]])
                break;else if (searchRes = [subStr isEqualToString:[searchString uppercaseString]])
                break;
        }

        if (searchRes)
            break;
    }

    if (searchRes && dismiss != YES) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        UIAlertView *linkAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Link Creation" message:@"Do you want to create link?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Create Link" otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
        [linkAlert setTag:1];  // for UIAlertView Delegate to handle which view is popped.
        [linkAlert show];
        MyAppAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [delegate setAlertRunning:YES];
        [linkAlert release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. This is very strange. I was able to duplicate the issue you're having, but it can't be an issue with NSString. You can verify this by creating an NSString like this NSString *hello = @"Hello&nbsp;World";. Then print that with NSLog. No, it's something to do with the UITextView's 'text' property. You might want to file a radar on this one. Maybe there is an explanation, but I have yet to find it. Will keep looking as this one is pretty interesting.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure anything else out with this one. I've tried other HTML codes and they all print fine. It's appears to just be &nbsp; I would file a bug: http://developer.apple.com/BugReporter/ -Matt

Comment: Thanks for looking Matt... nice to know I wasn't imagining it!

Answer (score 0):

do you want **&#160;**

which should be the same thing.

Comment: Thanks - Well, I guess either would work - but I need users to be able to see and verify - and they're used to `&nbsp;`  Or do you mean using that in code would display `&nbsp` in a UITextField?

Comment: Ahh, I think I get you - using &#160 would make it work as html when it gets sent to the website, yes?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to verify, but NSString **will not** automatically convert your HTML tags. What does your code look like that is causing this issue? NSString has -stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: but it just URL encodes the string. Seems quite strange, but there has to be an explanation. How about you show us some code. :-D